# Spring Data Couchbase findAll(Iterable)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase

I am using Spring Data findAll(Iterable) method to retrieve info from couchbase. However I am seeing null response.

I defined the below listed repository :

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, String> {

}
```

I am fetching the data by passing valid json

```
Iterable<Customer> custIter=customerRepository.findAll(customerList);
```

View is defined as below :

```
function (doc, meta) {  
   if(doc._class=="com.customer.model.types.Customer" ){
      emit(meta.id, doc); 
   } 
}
```

EDIT:

If I make a findOne call in a loop preceeding findAll call , findAll call returns data.

Comment: Are you seeing nulls in the returned iterable or a single null reference? Are you passing in a list of keys? Which version of SDC is that?

Comment: Hi Simon , I am just seeing a single null reference. I am passing list of keys like this - ["string1","string2"]. This is the version : org.springframework.data:spring-data-couchbase:1.3.2.RELEASE. This returns a null response when I use findAll.  But when I use findOne followed by findAll , findAll is returning the response. After running findOne once , even if I comment findOne , the subsequent findAll calls are the returning the result.

Comment: hey there. just a few quick comments:
1. not a good idea to emit 'doc' - it actually creates a duplicate doc (of the original) in the index. Rather, just get() the doc after you get the view-results.
2. also, meta.id is already emitted as part of the view data, so there's no sense in re-emitting it. you can just emit(null,null).
3. finally: you can debug your views at couchbase UI. just keep in mind that you might be seeing partial results if you have not published the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findAll being based on a view, I think this may be due to view indexation delay... Do you happen to recreate data just before you execute this code? IIRC no specific staleness criteria is used by this version so it should default to UPDATE_AFTER, which will resynchronize the index after the first query (which correspond to what you see with first findAll vs following ones...)

Comment: Thanks Simon. This occurs even if I try to fetch the data 5 minutes after the Dara is created and I assume it could be due to view indexation delay. Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure though, especially if the data has been there for 5mins... Is there a lot of data in the bucket?

Comment: No , it is our lower environment . I don't think there is a lot of data. But I can retry by waiting for longer duration and I'll retry the test.

Comment: Does it happens with findaAll() (the simple no parameter version)

Comment: No , I'll try that and update. Thanks for your guidance!!

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I just had an issue because of @FuzzyAmi's remark. Don't emit `(null, null)`, because the `findAll(Iterable<ID>)` method relies on the KEYS and not on the ID to find the documents. I had a view emitting `(null, null)` and `findAll(Iterable<ID>)` always returned an empty list. I think this should be documented in spring-data-couchbase javadoc.

Emit `(meta.id, null)` to be able to use spring-data-couchbase `findAll(Iterable<ID>)`.

@simon-baslé: I think the documentation should be updated.